# Caliburn.Micro: Call method of property on DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a MainView whose DataContext is my MainViewModel.

MainViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The ProjectViewModel.
    /// </summary>
    public ProjectViewModel ProjectVM
    {
        get { return _projectVM; }
        private set
        {
            _projectVM = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ProjectVM);
        }
    }
    private ProjectViewModel _projectVM;

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ProjectVM = new ProjectViewModel();
    }
}
```

Now, I have a Menu on my MainView. I want to bind the Click event of the MenItems to methods on the ProjectVM object. of course I know I can just set the DataContext of the MenuItems, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Currently my MainView looks like this:

```
  <Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Menu Grid.Row="0">
  <MenuItem Header="File">
    <MenuItem Header="New Project...">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
          <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ProjectVM.ShowNewProjectDialog"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Load Project..."/>
    <MenuItem Header="Close Project..."/>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I had hopes Caliburn was smart enough to resolve ProjectVM.ShowNewProjectDialog, but it isn't. Is there any good way to do this without having to set the DataContext of the Menu manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, Caliburn is not so smart to parse the `MethodName` property in the way that you wish. Anyway it is a powerful tool which can be easily customized depending on your needs.

As you can read in the Caliburn Micro Documentation section named [All About Actions](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions):

> ActionMessage is, of course, the Caliburn.Micro-specific part of this
>   markup. It indicates that when the trigger occurs, we should send a
>   message of “SayHello.” So, why do I use the language “send a message”
>   instead of “execute a method” when describing this functionality?
>   That’s the interesting and powerful part. ActionMessage bubbles
>   through the Visual Tree searching for a target instance that can
>   handle it.

It means that - if you need - you can manually set the "target" which will handle your message. You can do it by using the `Action.Target` attached property. Of course you do not want to set it for each `MenuItem`, so you can set directly in your `Menu` object:

```
<Menu cal:Action.Target="{Binding Path=ProjectVM, Mode=OneWay}">
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem Header="New Project..." cal:Message.Attach="ShowNewProjectDialog" />
        <MenuItem Header="Load Project..."/>
        <MenuItem Header="Close Project..."/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

By setting the `Action.Target` attached property we are declaring that all messages (i.e. ActionMessages) which come from a Menu's child will be handled by the `ProjectViewModel`.
Now if you run your project you will see that it does not work property. The reason is that Caliburn Micro uses the `VisualTreeHelper` for traversing the XAML tree. For our purpose we need to use the `LogicalTreeHelper`.

So the last step is to add this code in the `Bootstrapper` `Configure` method:

```
ActionMessage.SetMethodBinding = delegate(ActionExecutionContext context)
{
    FrameworkElement source = context.Source;
    for (DependencyObject dependencyObject = source; dependencyObject != null; dependencyObject = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject))
    {
        if (Caliburn.Micro.Action.HasTargetSet(dependencyObject))
        {
            object handler = Message.GetHandler(dependencyObject);
            if (handler == null)
            {
                context.View = dependencyObject;
                return;
            }
            MethodInfo methodInfo = ActionMessage.GetTargetMethod(context.Message, handler);
            if (methodInfo != null)
            {
                context.Method = methodInfo;
                context.Target = handler;
                context.View = dependencyObject;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if (source != null && source.DataContext != null)
    {
        object dataContext = source.DataContext;
        MethodInfo methodInfo2 = ActionMessage.GetTargetMethod(context.Message, dataContext);
        if (methodInfo2 != null)
        {
            context.Target = dataContext;
            context.Method = methodInfo2;
            context.View = source;
        }
    }
};
```

I hope it can help you.